# Does Swift copy on mutation in this scenario?

Tags: swift, memory

Essentially what I want is a temporary alias for a class property to improve readability.

I'm in the situation described by the following code and I can't see a straightforward solution. What I want to avoid is `y` being copied on mutation and then copied back.
Renaming `y` would reduce the readability of the actual algorithm a lot.

Is the Swift compiler smart enough to not actually allocate new memory and how would I be able to know that?

If not, how to prevent copying?

```
class myClass {
    var propertyWithLongDescriptiveName: [Float]

    func foo() {
        var y = propertyWithLongDescriptiveName
        // mutate y with formulas where y corresponds to a `y` from some paper
        // ...
        propertyWithLongDescriptiveName = y
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you try and make your question more clear? I don't understand completely. Are you asking if `y` is a copy of `propertyWithLongDescriptiveName`?

Comment: Which part are you worried about? A copy *of the backing store* is made once, when `y` is mutated the first time, but not for the both assignments.

Comment: Ah, ok. Good to know that only one copy happens. Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct Array` is a value types in Swift, which means that they are always
copied when assigned to another variable. However, each `struct Array`
contains pointers (not visible in the public interface) to the actual
element storage. Therefore after

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
var b = a
```

both `a` and `b` are (formally independent) values, but with pointers to the same element storage.
Only when one of them is *mutated,* a copy of the element storage is made.
This is called "copy on write" and for example explained in

- [Friday Q&A 2015-04-17: Let's Build Swift.Array](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html)

So after

```
b[0] = 17
```

`a` and `b` are values with pointers to different (independent) element  storage.
Further mutation of `b` does not copy the element  storage again 
(unless `b` is copied to another variable). Finally, if you assign
the value back

```
a = b
```

the old element storage  of `a` is released, and both values are pointers to the same storage again.

Therefore in your example:

```
    var y = propertyWithLongDescriptiveName
    // ... mutate y ...
    propertyWithLongDescriptiveName = y
```

a copy of the *element storage* is made exactly once (assuming
that you don't copy `y` to an additional variable).

If the array size does not change then a *possible* approach could be

```
var propertyWithLongDescriptiveName = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

propertyWithLongDescriptiveName.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { y in
    // ... mutate y ...
    y[0] = 13
}

print(propertyWithLongDescriptiveName) // [13.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

`withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer()` calls the closure with an
`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` to the element storage. 
A `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is a `RandomAccessCollection` and 
therefore offers an array-like interface.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear and concise. Since you don't mention a possible way to prevent any copy at all, I assume you agree with the two possible options (use NSArray or accept one copy) from the other answer?!

Comment: @FrederickSquid: NSMutableArray can hold only *objects,* which means that all floats are converted to NSNumber. That is probably more overhead.

Comment: @FrederickSquid: I have added another option. I agree with the other answer that you should check first if the allocation and copy is a performance problem at all.

Comment: Awesome! It's much simpler than I thought! I'll definitely profile to see if using `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` is warranted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, the Swift compiler is not that smart. All you need is a small test to see what it does:

```
class MyClass {
    var propertyWithLongDescriptiveName: [Float] = [1,2]

    func foo() {
        var y = propertyWithLongDescriptiveName
        y[0] = 3 // copied an mutated

        print(y)                               // [3,2]
        print(propertyWithLongDescriptiveName) // [1,2]
    }
}

let mc = MyClass()
mc.foo()
```

You have 2 optons:

- Change `propertyWithLongDescriptiveName` to `NSMutableArray`, which is a reference type
- Accept the overhead cost of copy-and-mutate to trade for readability of your algorithm. In many cases memory allocation cost is minimal compared to your algorithm's.